# Flutter Function to reload variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to make like a currency converter so I created this,

```
final montant = TextEditingController()..text = '500';
double convertEuro(montant) {
  double convtEur = (double.parse(montant.text) / 3.2);
  return convtEur;
}

double converted = 0;
```

I had a problem with my function here because the function when the screen loads it's null so I created that converted variable ( It's a stupid move I know at least to get rid of the error on my screen but only showing the initial value from my textController above

```
Text(
    "${double.parse(montant.text)}" +
        "DT = $converted" +
        " €",
 )
```

Anyway, the function is triggered when a button is pressed.

```
onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  converted = convertEuro(montant);
                }
              },
```

Can anyone help me how to change that variable value and make it change on my screen when the button is pressed?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `setState(() => converted = convertEuro(montant));` ?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך : Thank you . Last question Can I use it on multiple variables on same time .? like updating 3 or 4 variables in same setState?

Comment: Yes, you can set multiple variables. You can also just call the setState without any code inside of it. something like this: `setState(() {
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
setState(() {
  converted = convertEuro(montant);
});
```

In this, you're basically doing a rebuild of the widget.
Thus to implement this in your code, put `setState` under the `onPress`:

```
onPressed: () {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() {
      converted = convertEuro(montant);
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Yes great Thank you . Last question Can I use it on multiple variables on same time .? like updating 3 or 4 variables in same setState?

Comment: @LearningFlutterDev yes, you can.